# Understanding email headers: x-beenthere and x field

Tags: email, header

I'd like to understand more about the email headers.

After looking at one of the emails, I found the field had this entry "x-BeenThere" in the header. What does this mean?

Also I noticed some "x" fields seem like they're custom set fields, is this the case with some emails?

Comment: All field names beginning with `X-` are custom. This prefix is reserved for user/vendor experimentation, to avoid conflicting with standard headers.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `X-BeenThere` header is used by mailing list software to detect loops. Each time a message passes through a listserve, it adds its address to the header. If an incoming message already contains its address in the header, it means the message is looping (one of the recipients is forwarding their email to the list) and it's dropped.